# Enable store credit as payment option in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to figure out how to enable store credit as a payment option for Magento. I have set the settings in the below link, however, store credit is not showing up as a payment option.

Edit: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/customer-configuration-store-credit-options

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Jeff

Comment: Where is the link? What is store credit?

Comment: Have you flushed your cache?

Comment: I have flushed the cache, a couple of times =]

Answer (score 0):

The link you have posted contains information about 'Magento Go'. You are probably using the community edition. Store credit is available in the Magento core code only in Magento Go or Magento Enterprise Edition.

To use this functionality in community edition you will have to install a 3rd party extension.